# Accessing URL Parameter While Loading URL In Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to load an url in a div. And I also want to pass a parameter through that url. The value of the parameter is coming from a dropdown list. The div will only show up if any value is selected from that dropdown list, except a default value which is *"blank"* in my case. This is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var office;
var officeCode;
$("#mainPanel").hide();
$('#selectOfficeCode').change(function() {
  if ( this.value == 'blank')
  {
    $("#mainPanel").hide();
  }
  else
  {
    office=this.value;
    $("#mainPanel").show();
    $('#mainPanel').load('updateDirectorySelectedOffice.jsp?name='+office);
  }
});
});
</script>
```

And this is how I'm accessing the value of the parameter in updateDirectorySelectedOffice.jsp

```
<%
String selectedOfficeCode=request.getParameter("name");
System.out.println("Office"+selectedOfficeCode);
%>
```

This code is working fine in Chrome/Mozilla. I'm able to retrieve value of the passed parameter by above method in Chrome/Mozilla. But this code is not working in IE8. Any alternate way to do it in IE8?

Comment: Try with if ( $(this).val() == 'blank') condition instead. And office=$(this).val(); to retrieve select value.

Comment: Cool. That worked! Thanks..